# How do i use a click function to undo a click event?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple code here

```
         $("#faqs h4").click(function(){
                var div=$("div");
                    var h4=$("h4");       
                    h4.animate({letterSpacing:'0.1em'}, "slow");

                 });
```

When the h4 heading is clicked, the letters will space out to 0.1em. Now I can't figure out how to write another code so that it goes back to 0.0em when it is clicked again. Help! Thanks!

Comment: You're doing a couple things I'm not seeing corrected in the answers below: 1- you're setting this `div` variable, which never gets used 2- If you only want this to apply to the `#faqs h4` you've clicked, you'd be better off setting `var h4=$(this)`, which will apply its styling only to the clicked element. This could come in handy if you update the page later to include an h4 somewhere else you don't want spaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
$("#faqs h4").click(function(){
    var div=$("div");
    var h4=$("h4");
    var theSpacing = h4.css('letterSpacing');

    if (theSpacing == '0em') {
        h4.animate({letterSpacing:'0.1em'}, "slow");
    }
    else {
        h4.animate({letterSpacing: '0em'}, 'slow');
    }

});
```

or another way

```
var theSpacing = 0; // set a counter var to  use as a toggle method
$("#faqs h4").click(function(){
    var div=$("div");
    var h4=$("h4");

    if (theSpacing == 0) {
        h4.animate({letterSpacing:'0.1em'}, "slow");
        theSpacing += 1; // sets it not equal to 0 so on next click it will run the else statement
    }
    else {
        h4.animate({letterSpacing: '0em'}, 'slow');
        theSpacing = 0; // sets it equal to 0 so on next click will run the code in the if statement
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it using an external variable to contain the h4's spacing state:

```
var spaced = false;
$("#faqs h4").click(function(){
    var spacing = spaced ? '0em' : '0.1em'; // decide which spacing to use
    spaced = spaced ? false : true;         // set state to either or
    $(this).animate({letterSpacing: spacing}, "slow");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pyd6e/1/

**Edit:** as per Josh from Qaribou's comment, I hadn't noticed the way you are selecting your elements. You should be using `this` to refer to the current clicked h4 element, otherwise all of your h4s are going to be partying. Updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: Gets my vote for not duplicating the animate() logic, though this still contains the unused 'div' variable

Comment: @scrowler this works fine but the problem is if i do have multiple h2 elements it will rotate between each different h2 element clicked. So if i space out 1 h2 with a click, and try to space out a different h2 with a click it doesn't work because it wants to unspace that h2 even though it's already unspaced. But if i click the 2nd h2 again it will then space it.

Comment: Yes, you're right - it was an oversight. Use the original letterSpacing CSS attribute to decide whether to expand it or shrink it then as in @Stilly.stack's answer, or alternatively use CSS classes and `hasClass()`, `addClass()`, `removeClass()`